# By the time the teacher comes to class, the students.. (complete) their homework

Tags: verbs, future-tense

In this sentence:

> By the time the teacher comes to class, the students... (complete) their homework

In what tense should ***complete*** be?

Comment: Hello, Roro. If someone tells you that the _future perfect_ (as in 'By the time the teacher comes to class, the students will have completed their homework') is a construction  rather than a tense (though many websites will disagree), will that help you next time? 'Wat' and 'i' indicate that you need to work hard at the basics. And ELU, unlike many sites intended to help with the basics, is aimed at proficient linguists.

Comment: Don't worry abt wat, I... I use those as a short form as a quick way to write

Comment: I don't think this site encourages that, though. So I will edit your answer. But next time, unless it's a quote, please indulge us and write correctly. PS: Your answer will fly over to ELL pretty soon I think. (I would put "will have completed").

Comment: I meant your "question" not answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use future perfect in order to refer to an action that is expected to be completed in the future before another action.
Here, if we expect the completion of homework to happen before the teacher comes to the class in the future, we can say:

> By the time the teacher comes to class, the students will have completed their homework.